# php make checkbox checked based on mysql value

Tags: php, mysql

I have few check boxes which users can select..inside a form..I'm sending all the checked check boxes to database and saving them by imploding **','**..

Then again in html i'm exploding "," and getting data..But now i want to keep the check boxes which are already checked..How can i do that..I  have tried following..

```
$chkw = $works;
$chkecked = explode(',',$chkw);


<input name="work[]" value="doctor" type="checkbox" <?php echo $chkecked [0] == 'doctor' ? 'checked="checked"':'' ?>>
```

**But this way it is wrong..**

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `$chkecked[0] == 'doctor'` evaluates to `true`?

Comment: No that is the problem..it can change..not static @Darren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this one

```
<?php if(in_array('doctor',$chkecked)){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use curl instead file_get_content and then use binary transfer such as

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto)
{

    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```